# Moving a folder to a different folder in the user directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm developing a Minecraft client and I need to make an installer, I'm trying to move the folder to (%appdata%.minecraft\versions   or   C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\versions) but it always says incorrect syntax of the command, can anyone help me on this?

Code:

```
move ./PolarClient %appdata%\.minecraft\versions
pause
```

-Compo solved it.-

Comment: To begin with, unless you specify a path, the default for the source directory is the current directory, so there is no need to use a relative path, ```.\```, _(please note that Windows uses backward slashes, this is not 'nix)_. Also you should be in the habit of always double-quoting your source and destination too.

Comment: You should have said that as an answer you solved it!

Comment: You should use `if exist "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\" move /Y "%~dp0PolarClient" "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\"` to first check if the expected destination folder really exists and then move the file `PolarClient` from directory of the batch file of which full path always ending with a backslash is referenced with `%~dp0` to the destination folder. Well, it would be perhaps better to use `copy` instead of `move`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is space in the pathname, use double quotes like below.

```
move "./PolarClient %appdata%\.minecraft\versions"
pause
```